# is it possible to instantiate django object and then populate values?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a django model with a lot of fields so I don't want to create with a constructor.

I am trying to save like this:

```
org = Organization()
org.name = 'my name'
org.save()
```

but it is not saving.  How do I save and populate a django object in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, this is possible.

In your models.py make sure that every variable can accept null values:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

My guess is that if it isn't working then you have some required fields for instantiation.

Otherwise, to achieve the same flow you could create a dict name org and incrementally assign all of the variable just like it looks like you are doing and then pass them to the model like:

```
org = {... }
organization = Organization(**org)
```